Azure Communication Service for video call - incomingCall from/to in same time
I'm using Azure Communication Service to create video calls between 2 people (person 1 and person 2).
The first person to connect (for the example person 1) waits for the second to connect (for the example person 2).
When person 2 connects, they initiate the call.
Person 1 is therefore notified and must answer the call using this function:
callAgent.on('incomingCall', async (args) => {
    try {
        //show the button accept call
    } catch (error) {
    }
});

Automatically if a person does not answer the call is unsuccessful.
My problem is that when the 2 people launch the call at the same time, one of the 2 answers but the other being already connected to the call cannot answer so the call is disconnected as if it had not answered.
Is it possible to destroy incomingCall when the call is started?
EDIT WITH sampath SOLUTION :
this code seems to work
async function incomingCallHandler(args) {
    try {
        incomingCall = args.incomingCall;
            if(call.state === "Ringing" && call.direction === "Outgoing") {
                // hangup outgoing call
                await call.hangUp();
            }
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
};

callAgent.on('incomingCall', incomingCallHandler);


Steps for handling incoming calls and active calls simultaneously when both participants attempt to start a call at the same time:

Use the incomingCall event handler to listen for incoming calls. If the person is already on an active call, you may need to dismiss or decline the incoming call.
If a user is already in an active call and receives an incoming call, you can decline the incoming call automatically. Use args.call.reject() within the incomingCall event handler to decline the incoming call.
Assign a unique identifier to each call to ensure that calls from the same participants can be managed separately. This way, when a user is in an active call, any incoming call can be declined based on the unique identifiers.
The code was taken from git. Used this doc for incomingCall and Managing in an Azure Communication.


let activeCall = null;

callAgent.on('incomingCall', async (args) => {
    try {
        // Check if there is an active call already
        if (activeCall) {
            // Decline the incoming call automatically if the user is in an active call
            await args.call.reject();
            console.log('Incoming call declined because the user is in an active call.');
        } else {
            // Show the button to accept the incoming call
            // If accepted, set the call as activeCall
            activeCall = await args.accept();
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error handling incoming call:', error);
    }
});

// Sample code for initiating a call
async function initiateCall() {
    if (activeCall) {
        console.log('Already in a call, cannot initiate a new call.');
        return;
    }

    // Assuming you have a target user ID or phone number to call
    const targetUserIdentifier = { communicationUserId: '<USER_ID>' };
    try {
        activeCall = await callAgent.startCall([targetUserIdentifier]);
        console.log('Call initiated successfully');
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error initiating call:', error);
    }
}





I had tried something like that. But there is a delay between when the call is made and when it is received. The call can therefore be made without having yet received an incoming call when in reality there is an incoming call in progress but not yet received.

can add incomingCallInProgress = false; add  // Set the flag to indicate incoming call in progress   incomingCallInProgress = true;

Thanks, from your code I adapted it and it seems to work

Glad  know @usuakuser
